# C# HTML table from a website to a Datagridview

Tags: c#, html, web, datagridview

How can I read out a HTML text (`<table> ... </table>`) and put the tables into a Datagridview?

I tried it with WebClient to get the HTML code. But whats now the best way to design the tables into a Datagridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, the [`Html Agility Pack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood question right, You need parse html and then fill DataGridView. Html parsing can be done with [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).